# Parameter value '33.42922222' is out of range

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have an attribute of a table named ad Latitude, i have set its `data type` as `decimal(9,8) null` but when i try to insert the value `33.42922222` it gives me the error

> Parameter value '33.42922222' is out of range.

when i try to directly enter the value in the database table it gives the `Arithmetic overflow error`

i have tried to change the datatype to `numeric(9,8) null` but to no avail

please help me find out the problem ...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For clarification `DECIMAL(9,8)` is 1 digit before the decimal point and 8 digits after the decimal point.

So `DECIMAL(10,8)` should work for `33.42922222`.

[decimal and numeric (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Comment: tnx for the clarification, so then what datatype should i set to accommodate the desired value

Comment: @John: That depends on what you expect and what is allowed, but i have mentioned it in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

[Your precision is not enough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). Set precision according to the maximum value which you except. For example, if you expect 999,999 as the maximum value and you need a scale of 8, set it as decimal(14,8).